# Every intersection of a finite number of open subsets is also open

Tags: general-topology, logic

**Edit: former solution was deleted**

Assume

$$\bigcap_i  \Bbb C \setminus A_i \neq \emptyset, i = 1, ..., n.$$

Thus

$$\exists x \in \bigcap_i \Bbb C \setminus A_i,$$

and therefore

$$\exists x \in \Bbb C \setminus A_i \forall i = 1, ..., n,$$

(meaning: this specific $x$ is an element of every $A_i$)

and since $\Bbb C \setminus A_i$ is open for every $ i = 1, ...,n,$

$$\exists \epsilon \gt 0: B_\epsilon(x) \subset  \Bbb C \setminus A_i,$$

so it follows directly that

$$\exists \epsilon \gt 0: B_\epsilon(x) \subset \bigcap_i \Bbb C \setminus A_i.$$

Further questions:

We also have to prove the same statement for an intersection of an infinite number of subsets. I would assume that the intersection of an infinite number of those subsets leads to the empty set (which is open by definition) since intersecting an infinite number of subspaces of $\Bbb C$ makes $\Bbb C$ vanish. But I guess this is way too easy, isn't it? We already found a counterexample in our lecture notes, but I wasn't quite sure whether I could apply this or not. Its about intersecting ]$ \frac 1 n, \frac 1 n + 1 $[ for $n \in \Bbb N$, where an infinite number of intersections leads to the closed set [$0, 1$].

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit harsh to call it "utter nonsense," but I will agree that it doesn't make sense. To solve this you can do the following:

1. Pick a point in the intersection.
2. Find open balls around that point contained in each $\mathbb{C}-A_i$.
3. The intersection of the open balls is contained in the intersection of $\mathbb{C}-A_i$. You're finished if you can show that the intersection of these open balls contains an open ball around the original point. In fact, can you show that one of the open balls you picked is contained in all of the sets?

Comment: I need to think about it later on, thank you! Furthermore, I would like to know why this doesn't make sense. I guess I thought about something like this: If $x \in A$, and if x has a certain property, and if $x \in B$, then x also has this property in B. But I guess I can't generalize it like that, can I?

Comment: @Julian In general that's not true. It has to be justified.

Comment: Well, it might be interesting to show why this isn't true in this case then. :-) I'm also going to think about that. Oh, by the way, I guess at least the "formal-logic-part" of my proof is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @Julian for example $x$ is the only point in $\{x\}$, and $x\in \{x,y\}$, but $x$ is not the only point in the latter set.

Comment: Well you wrote or when it should be and. Or gives you the union.

Comment: By the way, the title had a correct statement in it, but that's not what you're trying to prove. I changed the title, but not the body.

Comment: Well, the title was just the exact translation of our task. (given in German) So this is what I have to justify.